# Javascript Regular Expression to match 5 or 9 digit zipcode

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a similar issue as my recent post but with a zip code validator, I am trying to convert over to a javascript validation process.  my script looks like so:

```
    var regPostalCode = new RegExp("\\d{5}(-\d{4})?");
    var postal_code = $("input[name='txtzipcode']").val();
    if (regPostalCode.test(postal_code) == false) {
        bValid = false;
        msg = msg + '<li>Invalid Zip Code.</li>';
    }
```

From my recent post, I learned of the escape character that I needed at the beginning.

Basically, this function is validating a zip code that says `22601` which is correct, but it shouldn't validate `22601-1`. There should have to be 4 digits after the dash like `22601-9999`. It's like the second part of the validation is always true.  Again this expression has worked in the past for me.  Am I missing something?  Is another escape character needed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add anchors: `new RegExp("^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$")`. This forces the regular expression engine to only accept a match, if it begins at the first character of the string (`^`) and ends at the end of the string (`$`) being matched.

Note, that there might be a typo in the regular expression you hav given in your question: the second `\d` is missing a backslash.

Comment: This was the fix.  No typo, just another bug.  Thanks for the explanation as well as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to:

```
new RegExp("^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$")
```