# PHP simple regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate a string only if it contains '0-9' chars with length between 7 and 9.

What I have is [0-9]{7,9} but this matches a string of ten chars too, which I don't want.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435435/another-javascript-regular-expression-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find 7-9 digit numbers inside a larger string, you can use [a negative lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to verify the match isn't preceded or followed by a digit

```
(?<![0-9])[0-9]{7,9}(?![0-9])
```

This breaks down as

- `(?<![0-9])` ensure next match is not preceded by a digit
- `[0-9]{7,9}` match 7-9 digits as you require
- `(?![0-9])` ensure next char is not a digit

If you simply want to ensure the entire string is a 7-9 digit number, anchor the match to the start and end with ^ and $

```
^[0-9]{7,9}$
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use `^[0-9]{7,9}$`.

^ matches the beginning of the string, while $ matches the end.